# How to send MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED and MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON in same request body using RestTemplate

Tags: spring, openid, resttemplate

I need to send "client_id" and "client_secret" parameters in request body as MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED and another object as MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON in same RestTemplate request. 
Is it possible?